# Generate Keypair with PKCS#11 on curve secp256r1 and sign with it

Tags: go, cryptography, signature, pkcs#11

I'm trying to generate an EC-Keypair with PKCS#11 on SoftHSM2 with `github.com/miekg/pkcs11`

I got curve-parameters from here:
https://github.com/ANSSI-FR/libecc/blob/master/src/curves/known/ec_params_secp256r1.h

But I'm still getting `CKR_GENERAL_ERROR`, here is my function to sign:

```
func sign() {
  lib := "/usr/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so"
  p := pkcs11.New(lib)
  if p == nil {
    fmt.Printf("Lib not found ", lib)
    return
  }

  p.Initialize()
  defer p.Destroy()
  defer p.Finalize()
  slots, _ := p.GetSlotList(true)
  session, _ := p.OpenSession(slots[0], pkcs11.CKF_SERIAL_SESSION|pkcs11.CKF_RW_SESSION)
  defer p.CloseSession(session)
  p.Login(session, pkcs11.CKU_USER, "xxx")
  defer p.Logout(session)

  //    pkcs11.CKK_ECDSA                            = 0x00000003
    // pkcs11.CKK_EC                               = 0x00000003
    // pkcs11.CKK_X9_42_DH                         = 0x00000004
  // pkcs11.CKK_SEED                             = 0x0000002F
  //    pkcs11.CKC_X_509                            = 0x00000000

  //pkcs11.CKA_OBJECT_ID                        = 0x00000012
  //pkcs11.CKA_NEVER_EXTRACTABLE                = 0x00000164
  //    CKA_EC_PARAMS                        = 0x00000180
  //    CKA_EC_POINT                         = 0x00000181
  publicKeyTemplate := []*pkcs11.Attribute{
  pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_CLASS, pkcs11.CKO_PUBLIC_KEY),
  pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_KEY_TYPE, pkcs11.CKK_EC),
  //pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_OBJECT_ID, 1),
  pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_EC_PARAMS, []byte{
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
    0xBC, 0xE6, 0xFA, 0xAD, 0xA7, 0x17, 0x9E, 0x84,
    0xF3, 0xB9, 0xCA, 0xC2, 0xFC, 0x63, 0x25, 0x51}),//[]byte{0x06, 0x09, 0x2B, 0x06, 0x01, 0x04, 0x01, 0xDA, 0x47, 0x0F, 0x01}),
  //pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_EC_POINT, 3),
  //pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_EXTRACTABLE, true),
  pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_TOKEN, true),
  //pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_ENCRYPT, true),
  //pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT, []byte{3}),
  //pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_MODULUS_BITS, 1024),
  //pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_LABEL, "Null"),
  }
  privateKeyTemplate := []*pkcs11.Attribute{
  pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_CLASS, pkcs11.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY),
  pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_KEY_TYPE, pkcs11.CKK_EC),
  //pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_OBJECT_ID, 2),
  pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_EC_PARAMS, []byte{
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
    0xBC, 0xE6, 0xFA, 0xAD, 0xA7, 0x17, 0x9E, 0x84,
    0xF3, 0xB9, 0xCA, 0xC2, 0xFC, 0x63, 0x25, 0x51}),
  //pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_EC_POINT, 3),
  //pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_NEVER_EXTRACTABLE, true),
  pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_TOKEN, true),
  pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_PRIVATE, true),
  pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_SIGN, true),
  pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_ENCRYPT, true),
  //pkcs11.NewAttribute(pkcs11.CKA_LABEL, "Null"),
  }
  _, priv, err := p.GenerateKeyPair(session,
  []*pkcs11.Mechanism{pkcs11.NewMechanism(pkcs11.CKM_EC_KEY_PAIR_GEN, nil)}, //pkcs11.CKM_EC_KEY_PAIR_GEN
  publicKeyTemplate, privateKeyTemplate)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  p.SignInit(session, []*pkcs11.Mechanism{pkcs11.NewMechanism(pkcs11.CKM_ECDSA_SHA1, nil)}, priv)
  // Sign something with the private key.
  data := []byte("Lets sign this data")

  _, err = p.Sign(session, data)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  fmt.Printf("It works!")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that this code sample lacks quality and more information would be helpful it mainly seems that mainly the templates are wrong:

Mechanism `CKM_EC_KEY_PAIR_GEN` only needs the curve OID in `CKA_EC_PARAMS` (the commmented part is right, the actual code is wrong) in the public key template only. `CKA_CLASS` and `CKA_KEY_TYPE` are set automatically for both keys as well as `CKA_EC_PARAMS` for the private key (see https://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-curr/v3.0/os/pkcs11-curr-v3.0-os.html#_Toc30061186).

You can add `CKA_TOKEN`, `CKA_LABEL` or `CKA_ID` (note: `CKA_OBJECT_ID` is only defined for a data object, not a key).
Start with this, not more. Then add usage restrictions (`CKA_SIGN` etc) as needed.

Comment: I did not ask for a review, I asked in general how to program such stuff...

Comment: The commented part is _an_ OID but it is apparently for ed25519 (but not the correct OID from rfc8410) NOT for secp256r1 aka prime256v1 aka P-256.

Comment: First paragraph referred to an original comment that has been removed in the meantime. Rest of answer actually answers how you use C_GenerateKeyPair with CKM_EC_KEY_PAIR_GEN. I've overlooked that the OID is wrong, for secp256r1 it is 0x06, 0x08, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0xCE, 0x3D, 0x03, 0x01, 0x07

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but its not displayed... I thank you, things are more clear to me now.

Comment: I got the oid for ed25519 from here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/81023/oid-for-ed25519

Comment: I deduced from original question that you want to create a secp256r1 key. For an Ed25519 key PKCS #11 std says that you either need to specify the curveName of RFC8032 or the oID of RFC8410. The latter does not only denote the curve but actually the algorithm itself.

Comment: While I'm on my way with softhsm2 supporting pkcs#11 2.40 I dont think, that I can generate ed25519 at all. Its supported since version 3.0?

Comment: Or can some1 send me the code-snippet, to do that?